# How do I display the "advanced tab" in Sql Server Import & Export Wizard?

Tags: sql-server

I use SQL Server 2008 R2 and I would like to import a Excel File to DB Azure.

But I have a problem : I don't have the "advanced tab" when I import Data. Is it normal (it's to solve a truncation problem) ?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is normal. 
To fix a truncation problem you will need to edit the mappings which happens several windows further on from the point of your screenshot.

click 'next','next','next'. Brings you to "Select Source tables and
    views" window.
  Select the excel sheet you want to import and
    click 'edit mappings'. Change the type or size setting as
    appropriate for your case.